# JavaScript: How To Make A Prompt Happen Later

Tags: javascript

This is a very basic question but how do you make a prompt appear later after the webpage has loaded?  My code for the prompt looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.prompt("Prompt Here!")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What can I use to make the file execute the prompt after a little while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.prompt("Prompt Here!");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: *"how do you make a prompt appear later **after the webpage has loaded**? "*

Comment: Guess it depends what the original poster was really looking for. He also said "*What can I use to make the file execute the prompt after a little while?*"

Comment: ***later** after the webpage has loaded*. a mixture of both your answers would fit that

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.body.onload = function(){
    window.prompt("Prompt Here!");
});
```

Or:

```
<body onload="window.prompt('Prompt Here!');">
```